# What is the bandwidth of a spectrometer?

Tags: spectroscopy

I would be really interested to know how the bandwidth of spectrometer is exactly defined. Does somebody has an answer? Also, if I want to generate a signal with steep edges, e.g. a nearly ideal rectangular pulse, what do I have to consider concerning the bandwidth of the spectrometer?

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352894/104696

Comment: A bit, but the main question is that I just want to know how exactly the bandwidth of a spectrometer is defined.

Comment: This and the linked question use the term [spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrometer) but, particularly in the answer at the link, a [spectrum analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_analyzer) seems to be what is described.

Comment: Is this question in regards to an optical spectrometer or an electrical spectrum analyzer?

Comment: Optical spectrometer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to distinguish between RBW ( Resolution Bandwidth ) and the bandwidth of the spectrum analyzer. The RBW is adjustable and provides the sensitivity of the frequency spectrum that the analyzer will detect whereas the spectrum analyzer itself will have a bandwidth which defines the maximum frequencies with which the device can discriminate.

The purpose of the spectrum analyzer is to break up the analyzed signal into a Fourier Transform describing its fundamental frequency and harmonic frequencies and their relative amplitudes.

In order to do this properly, the RBW must be less than the difference between the fundamental and harmonic frequencies being observed. For a square wave, the harmonics are all odd multiples of the fundamental frequency, so the RBW must be less than 2 x fundamental frequency in order to resolve the harmonics.

In addition, the fundamental frequency must be much less than the instrument's bandwidth in order to see sufficient harmonics of the square wave. The exact number is a matter of practicality. As a minimum you'd need at least the 5th harmonic but more is better. That means that you'd be at the very least limited to observing a square wave signal with a fundamental frequency of one fifth of the instrument's bandwidth.

As with all bandwidth definitions, both of these bandwidths are defined by their 3db levels ( or half power levels ). The RBW is defined by the bandwidth of the RBW filter. The low pass and high pass cutoff frequencies of the filter are defined by frequencies at which 3db less power than the mid band frequency of the filter is passed through the filter. The filter bandwidth is defined as high cut off frequency - low cutoff frequency.

Similarly, the instrument bandwidth will have a high cutoff frequency and possibly a low cutoff frequency for which it accurately measures the power levels of those frequencies. In some cases, the low cutoff frequency might be 0 Hz if there is no baseband limiting circuitry. There will always, however, be a high frequency limitation to any electronic circuit. Once again, the cutoff frequencies will be defined by the 3db frequencies and the bandwidth = high cutoff frequency - low cutoff frequency.